# Using Ansible vault for Ansible's ssh keyfile

Tags: ansible

I've used Ansible vault to store an ssh keyfile to be installed on remote boxes.  But I'm having difficulty getting Ansible to use a private key for its own operation.

I can specify a keyfile in ansible.cfg with "private_key_file".  That's fine but I really want to encrypt that file at rest.  I tried simply making it a vault file, but it doesn't seem to decrypt it first - just tries to use it as is I guess.

I would love to be able to specify in my inventory/group_vars/all a new variable, something like:

```
ssh_private_key: |
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But, while there is the "private_key_file" variable, there doesn't seem to be a "private_key" (or similar) variable.

This ansible setup, the keyfile included, will be put into git and multiple admins will pull it - it really ought not to be plaintext.  Any suggestions for a simple solution?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Not I, but a fellow geek did.  Unfortunately, I don't have the code from that contract.  Ansible can execute a script when it needs the private key.  He set it to pull the key from a remote server and decrypt it.

Answer (score 4):

Although I see there is a [long-standing request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991392/using-ansible-vault-for-ansibles-ssh-keyfile) open for this, my understanding is that the SSH private key must be reachable to the underlying OpenSSH software, adding complexity, and complexity usually doesn't cope very well with security.

My preferred solution for this is to :

- Generate and store SSH keys the standard way using `ssh-keygen` and a strong password to encrypt them. The keys being properly secured, they can be handled as any of your other vaulted secrets. This is also useful as it allows easier and safer debugging since you can also directly use the keys with a traditional `ssh -i`, something you wouldn't be able to do with vaulted keys.
- **In your inventory:** Add two variables to your hosts, lets say *ssh_key_file* and *ssh_key_pass*, to associate a private key path and its password for each one of them (or to each group, etc., depending on your setup).
- **In your playbook:** Use the [Expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) module to automatically add the SSH keys to the SSH-agent upon playbook start:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  # Postpone facts gathering until SSH keys have been unlocked
  gather_facts: no

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Unlock SSH key "{{ ssh_key_file }}"
      expect:
        command: ssh-add "{{ ssh_key_file }}"
        responses:
          passphrase: "{{ ssh_key_pass }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      become: no
      changed_when: no
      no_log: true

    - name: Gathering facts
      setup:

  tasks:
    # Do some stuff...
    # ...

  post_tasks:
    # Optional, to remove the keys from the agent at the end:
    - name: Lock SSH key "{{ ssh_key_file }}"
      command: ssh-add -d "{{ ssh_key_file }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      become: no
      changed_when: no
```

This way the Ansible vault password will be sufficient to unlock all the resources required by Ansible to do its duty, while still storing all your keys and secrets in a secure manner.

Comment: Throws `"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."` Required to start and connect to ssh-agent

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in the inventory/group_vars/all

```
ssh_private_key: |
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and encrypt the file inventory/group_vars/all. Then in your playbook have the below content at the start.

```
- name: Copy SSH private key
  copy:
    content: "{{ ssh_private_key }}"
    dest: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    mode: 0600
```

When running the playbook include the --ask-vault-pass to prompt vault password. I tried this and it worked in my local.

For more information check the below link. 
https://therealmarv.com/ansible-vault-file-handling/

Comment: The goal isn't to copy a private key to a remote box.  It's to tell Ansible to use an encrypted private key for its own ssh.